# If madhiy comes out before semen is ejaculated, and then semen is ejaculated, is the semen mixed with madhiy considered najis?

Tags: practical-islam, sunni, taharah, najis

If madhiy comes out before the ejaculation of semen, and then semen is ejaculated, and then the semen mixes with the madhiy, is the semen mixed with madhiy considered to be pure or najis? I'm of the view that semen is pure. So please answer from this point of view and mention difference of opinion from this point of view. Thank you.

Note : I think that if semen is ejaculated after madhiy is discharged, and the semen mixes with madhiy, the semen may purify the madhiy here as the semen overwhelms the madhiy. And I'm also of the view that says pure liquid other than water can be used to purify impurity. But this is just an assumption. My question is written above, I mainly need answer of that.

Comment: The case you are describing doesn't exist in fiqh because either you have Madhy or you have Madhy followed by maniy and there's no doubt as little of maniy doesn't exist.

Comment: @Medi1Saif probably you didn't understand my question. I am not sure what you are talking about regarding little amount of maniy. I am asking about madhiy followed by maniy. That means madhiy comes out before the ejaculation and then the semen is ejaculated. So the semen mixes with the madhiy.

Comment: You cannot clean with something else than water!

Comment: @Sassir https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111812/can-najaasah-be-purified-without-water

Comment: That's a minority view which needs backup that I can't find mentioned there.

Comment: @Sassir Just because a view is a minority view doesn't mean it is wrong. There are many opinions where the minority view seems to be more correct. And there is logic behind this opinion and this view was favored by Shiekh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyya and Ibn ‘Uthaymeen. But you should follow the opinion that you feel is more closer to the truth. If the view seems to be weak in your opinion then follow the opinion that you feel is the most authentic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer to this question.

IslamQA says:

> Any liquid other than water is to be regarded as being like water when something impure (najis) is mixed with it, so it becomes impure if the impure substance remains there and its effects are visible in it. And the liquid is deemed to be pure if no change occurs in it and no trace of the impurity is visible.

Source: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/343109/do-the-secretions-from-a-womans-uterus-become-najis-impure-when-mixed-with-madhiy-prostatic-fluid

The site talks about secretions from a woman's uterus which is pure being mixed with madhiy. And this question here is about semen mixed with madhiy.

Answer (score 1):

The fatwa you refer to nowhere mentioned maniy as such a cleaning liquid. In fact using it would be controversial or doubtful as the majority view is that it is not tahir.
And it is always better to avoid controversial topics. As stated in the Sahih hadith:

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, 'Both legal and illegal things are evident but in between them there are doubtful (suspicious) things and most of the people have no knowledge about them. So whoever saves himself from these suspicious things saves his religion and his honor. And whoever indulges in these suspicious things is like a shepherd who grazes (his animals) near the Hima (private pasture) of someone else and at any moment he is liable to get in it. (O people!) Beware! Every king has a Hima and the Hima of Allah on the earth is His illegal (forbidden) things. Beware! There is a piece of flesh in the body if it becomes good (reformed) the whole body becomes good but if it gets spoilt the whole body gets spoilt and that is the heart.
> ([Sahih al-Bukahri](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:52))

A more detailed discussion of this hadith can be found in the answer of your former question: [What is the evidence regarding the fact that doing something makruh is not sinful but one who stays away from it for the sake of Allah is rewarded?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/74700/what-is-the-evidence-regarding-the-fact-that-doing-something-makruh-is-not-sinfu)

Further maniy can't remove madhy as it is part of it and that was the condition for accepting a liquid for cleaning as stated by ibn Taymiyyah and abu Hanifa too as stated in the fatwa on islamqa #[111812](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/111812/can-najaasah-be-purified-without-water) you've mentioned in the comments:

> The view of Imam Abu Haneefah (may Allaah have mercy on him) is that **it is acceptable to purify najaasah with any pure liquid that can remove it**.
> This view was also favoured by Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allaah have mercy on him). It says in al-Ikhtiyaaraat al-Fiqhiyyah (p. 23):
> **Najaasah may be purified with any pure liquid that will remove it**, such as vinegar and the like. This was narrated in one report from Ahmad, and was favoured by Ibn ‘Aqeel, and it is the view of the Hanafis. End quote.

However it is rather the case that maniy itself can or must be removed by either washing it while it is still liquid or not dried yet or scratching it when it became dry in order to follow the sunnah as practiced at the time of the prophet ().